# Use a nil context, but do not panic and hang there. How could this possible?

Tags: go, panic

```
type Etcd struct {
    Next       plugin.Handler
    Fall       fall.F
    Zones      []string
    PathPrefix string
    Upstream   upstream.Upstream // Proxy for looking up names during the resolution process
    Client     etcdc.KeysAPI
    Ctx        context.Context
    Stubmap    *map[string]proxy.Proxy // list of proxies for stub resolving.

    endpoints []string // Stored here as well, to aid in testing.
}


func (e *Etcd) get(path string, recursive bool) (*etcdc.Response, error) {
    if e.Ctx == nil {
            // run here
            log.Printf("e.Ctx is nil")
    }
    // hang here but not panic.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(e.Ctx, etcdTimeout)
    defer cancel()
    r, err := e.Client.Get(ctx, path, &etcdc.GetOptions{Sort: false, Recursive: recursive})
    if err != nil {
            return nil, err
    }
    return r, nil
}
```

source code link:
https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/v1.0.6/plugin/etcd/etcd.go#L87

I used this etcd package in my own project, and init it, but not initialize filed Ctx, and I found that the process hang at this code:

> ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(e.Ctx, etcdTimeout)

how could this happen with e.Ctx is nil and context.WithTimeout() do not panic ?

Anyone's suggestion is helpful.

Comment: go version is v1.9.2.

Comment: Process hangs meaning it never exits?

Comment: Have you ever tried initialising the context if it's `nil`? Also this:

[Do not pass a nil Context, even if a function permits it. Pass context.TODO if you are unsure about which Context to use.](https://golang.org/pkg/context/)

Comment: @Adrian yes ,it never exists.

Comment: @Havelock i know the right way to use context, but i do not know why the context is nil, but context.WithTimeout() function does not panic.

Comment: @leebreeze: if the program is blocked, get a stack trace and see where. Is the panic being recovered somewhere?